# WCF: Service calling service in same assembly

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service (hosted in IIS 6) with two services, FileMonitorService ans JobService. In one of FileMonitorService's methods I want to call a method in JobService through WCF. This method in JobService is executed asynchronously (fire and forget).

I suppose it'd be easy enough use a Thread Pool and signal when they are all done.. I'd rather use WCF though (this is a personal project, so I'm just trying out new things).

edit:
I came across these two posts, but they addressed WCF services across different servers.
[Calling a WCF service from another WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516683/calling-a-wcf-service-from-another-wcf-service)
[calling a WCF service object method in another WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049560/calling-a-wcf-service-object-method-in-another-wcf-service)

edit 2: Clarification on question:

Less a question I suppose than more of a request for thoughts on the approach.

Comment: Is there a reason for not wanting to call the method directly asynchronously?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. I'm just soliciting thoughts on the approach. I could call the method directly, was thinking I could take advantage of WCF's threading. Conceptually, what I'm trying to do is fire a service (from within the service) that is "fire and forget". As I write this, it occurs to me that a more appropriate solution may be to fire a WF process, since in effect, that's what I'm doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it through WCF only adds overhead so you should call the method in JobServices directly unless you have a compelling reason to not to do so.
Given the limited amount of context, I would stick with the ThreadPool if I were you.

Comment: I agree I think. As I mentioned in my comment above, I realized that instead of a service, what the initial WCF service is basically doing is kicking off a workflow.. So I think WF may be the best solution in this case.

Comment: Nope, went with your suggestion Alfred and the JobServices uses ThreadPool directly.